# Check in controller which input element has been modified

Tags: angularjs, input, updatemodel, angularjs-forms

I need to check which input element has modified in update form.

```
    <form name="utilizationForm" role="form" novalidate>
    <div class="row" data-ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4]">
            <div class="col-md-3"> 
                <div asterick class="form-group" ng-class="{'form-group has-success': !error['resource_type'] && (submitted), 'form-group has-error': (error['resource_type']) && (submitted)}"> 
                    <label for="resourceType">Resource Type</label>
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" class="form-control" ng-model="data['id' + i]" value="">
                                        <select name="resourceType" id="resourceType" ng-model="data['resource_type' + i]" class="form-control" ng-required="true"  >
                                            <option ng-repeat="option in resourceTypeJson" value="{{option}}">{{option}}</option>
                                        </select>
                    <span class="er-block" ng-show="utilizationForm.resourceType.$touched && utilizationForm.resourceType.$error.required">Please provide Resource type.</span>
                    <span ng-show="error.resource_type1" class="er-block">{{error.resource_type1}}</span>
                </div>    
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <label for="efforts">Efforts (in hours)</label>
                <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" class="form-control" ng-model="data['id' + i]" value="">
                <input type="text"  test-change name="efforts" id="efforts" class="form-control" ng-model="data['efforts' + i]"  value="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="text-right" ng-class="{'col-md-6 mt25': showCompletion}">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="utilizationForm.$invalid" ng-click="addUtilizationReport()">{{buttonText}}</button>
        </div>

    </form>
```

Now when I click on update button I need to check which input element has modified in update form in controller. Please help.

Comment: you can check that by **$watch**

Comment: How can i use this in controller. I don't have much idea about angular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put the input in a form with a name attribute and then give the input a name attribute, you can also access the input's `$dirty` property.

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
  <form name="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="first" ng-model="firstName">
    <input type="text" name="last" ng-model="lastName">
  </form>
</div>
```

```
app.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
  // Here you have access to the inputs' `$dirty` property
  console.log($scope.myForm.first.$dirty);
  console.log($scope.myForm.last.$dirty);
});
```

You can use `$scope.myForm.$dirty` to see if any fields have changed, and the `$dirty` property on each input's property on the form to see if that input has changed. You can even iterate over the `myForm` object (non-input-field objects have keys prefixed with a `$`):

```
angular.forEach($scope.myForm, function(value, key) {
  if(key[0] == '$') return;
  console.log(key, value.$dirty)
});
```

Comment: Your example always returning true on date field even i am not changing that date input, I am using a date picker which have text input

Comment: it might be the case the initial value of model variable is getting updated after page rendering. This is standard way given by angular itself . for more details you can refer this link https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController

Comment: Thank you @Dhiraj for your support. It really helped me to overcame my problem.

Comment: You are welcome. I had also gone through same problem in my project.Keep up the good work and learning.

Comment: For more information, see [AmgularJS Developer Guide - Forms](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms)

Comment: I kinda need advice related to the same kind of problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47333804/cannot-read-property-pristine-of-undefined-when-string-used-as-input-name

Answer (score 1):

Here is simplest example of using $watch in controller:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('appCtrl', function($scope, $location) {
    $scope.$watch('abc', function(newVal,oldVal) {
      if(oldVal != newVal){
        alert("value changed!");
      }    
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="appCtrl">
 <input type="text" name="first" ng-model="abc">
</div>
```

Comment: this can be other approach ,i up voted it but this is for watching the scope variable change. If you look at his question he was needing to get only dirty fields from form .