# Cannot read property '$pristine' of undefined when string used as input name

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

In my form I have an ng-repeat and within that ng-repeat I have a bunch of fields. Sometimes there could be 3 fields, sometimes there might just be one.

I have an angular for each to check $pristine for a specific field. The name of the field pretty much stays the same but the field count number changes so I thought I would check it like this:

```
var price = "price_" + product.line_no;

console.log($scope.myform.price.$pristine); = console.log($scope.myform."price_1".$pristine);
```

But I am getting this:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '$pristine' of undefined
```

Comment: The error is telling you that $scope.myform.price is undefined. Why is it undefined?

Comment: @Mayday My assumption is that it's not taking into account the `price` variable as an input name but i'm not sure why this is.Even though it is being populated as `price_1`

Comment: How did you define `$scope.myform.price`? In your code, you only defined a string variable called price

Comment: I haven't defined it. Should I be doing so? What i'm essentially trying to accomplish is if i use manually `console.log($scope.myform.price_1.$pristine)` it returns a value but if I set a variable with the field name and the line number and use it within `console.log($scope.myform.price.$pristine)` it breaks it.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have set unique name attribute in your input field.
Here is a fiddler that can help  https://jsfiddle.net/paka2/n6weLg55/

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products">
<input name="price_{{$index}}" type="text" ng-model="productList['price_' + $index]" required/>
</div>
```